# Simulate mouse and keyboard input in C++ 

Tags: c++, cross-platform

I am looking for a way to simulate mouse and keyboard input in C++. I am looking for a cross-platform library that will help me achieve this. Any suggestions?

Target platforms are desktop platforms... Linux, Mac, and Windows only.

Comment: Voting to close as tool rec.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, input device simulation is extremely platform specific, and finicky even on a single platform. It is not a robust technique for any purpose, so you will not find good libraries to implement it.

The part which is most difficult, once you have the fundamental APIs, is making the devices look realistic to the OS. You want gradual mouse movement updates to be sent at a moderately high frequency, like a mouse would do, and reasonable delays between clicks and keypresses. Executing a timeline of events and doing the basic geometry would probably be assisted by a game library like SDL.

If you ignore timing, the OS may decimate mouse motion, debounce buttons, rearrange the order of motion and clicks, ignore keypresses while the trackpad is in use, etc. I wrote just such a tool almost 10 years ago.

Comment: I looked into SDL and talked with some people in the SDL irc, but they seem to think it wouldn't allow key presses on anything but the application it was written for.  Maybe they didn't know, but it seemed genuine.  I'll give it a shot if you know otherwise.

Comment: @Goddard SDL will help you generate a timeline of desired actions and call your callbacks on time. I did not suggest it would generate keypresses.

Comment: I see...it appears finding a solution in C/C++ is very difficult.  I have basically given up the search for an existing library that can help me achieve my goal.

Comment: @KimJongWoo You need to post your comment under his question, not my answer. He didn't get your message.

Answer (score 1):

I started such a Library, maybe you want cast a glance. 
https://github.com/pythoneer/XInputSimulator

Its in an early state and as the time of writing a bit buggy. But i hope its getting better :)

Answer (score 0):

Although the input libraries are platform specific, so are the GUI but there are abstract libraries available for such as wxWdigets and Qt which hides the complexity and for input I found this one to be quite interesting

https://github.com/jkuhlmann/gainput