# Howto send keystrokes with V-Lang

Tags: vlang

I want to send keystrokes with V lang to try to create a testing tool. How can I do that?

Like `send(enter)` or something like that

Comment: Command line or graphical app?

Comment: Command line for a while, but graphical method will be needed soon

Answer (score 1):

I'll recommend you look at the [`examples` directory](https://github.com/vlang/v/tree/master/examples).
It's very, very, feature rich :)

For terminal input specifically you can look at the `term.ui` module:
[Here's an example](https://github.com/vlang/v/blob/b2945e916fcaaa8074cf7e75ce6b5dbe1a465739/examples/term.ui/pong.v#L77) from `pong.v`.

If you do not need all the bells and whistles of `term.ui` you can use the [`readline`](https://modules.vlang.io/readline.html) module.

For graphical apps there's both `gg` and the lower level `sokol` modules.
`gg` example using input [here](https://github.com/vlang/v/blob/b2945e916fcaaa8074cf7e75ce6b5dbe1a465739/examples/gg/mandelbrot.v#L135-L170) - and `sokol` example [here](https://github.com/vlang/v/blob/b2945e916fcaaa8074cf7e75ce6b5dbe1a465739/examples/sokol/particles/particles.v#L120-L146).

Comment: I want to write a keystoke, not to read one

Comment: I see. In that case you'll currently need to generate OS events yourself [which isn't necessarily done easily](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10100458/1904615)